# Terraform aws_lb_listener_rule Condition "Unsupported block type"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, listener, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to create a terraform `aws_lb_listener_rule` resource and am getting the error "Unsupported block type - Blocks of type "host_header" are not expected here." (and the same error for the path_pattern) when I run `terraform plan`.

I'm using terraform 0.12 and upgraded the folder from 0.11 so there's a version.tf file with `required_version = ">= 0.12"`. I'm using this link as a reference https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener_rule.html

This is the resource block I'm using

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "260" {
  listener_arn = data.terraform_remote_state.alb.outputs.alb_https_listener_arn
  priority     = 260

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = module.x.target_group_arn
  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["something.com"]
    }
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/a/*", "/b/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the this setup in other files I have so I know it can run successfully. I'm wondering if there's a conflicting resource or something else I'm missing that's causing the error.

I am using the deprecated condition version in the same folder in a different file if that would cause an issue. When I isolate that resource and try to modify it it still gives me the error so I might need to delete the rule and then recreate it with the new way.

I've tried deleting the `.terraform` file and running terraform init again to see if that would reset anything, re-arranging the conditions if that had anything to do with it, and copying the exact code from the doc and modifying it but it still throws the error.

I can use the deprecated condition

```
condition {
  field  = "path-pattern"
  values = ["/a/*", "/b/*"]
}
```

I've been searching online for a similar problem and had trouble finding that matches this issue.

Comment: The `host_header` block was added in version 2.42.0 of the AWS provider. Are you using at least that version? (You can run `terraform version` in an initialized working directory to see your Terraform CLI version and all of the installed provider versions.)

Comment: That is absolutely what was happening! I was using version 2.33 and deleting the .terraform folder and running `terraform init -upgrade` downloaded the update AWS provider version. Thank you